# Haskell: TLS not supported error in mime-mail-ses

Tags: email, haskell, mime-mail

I am getting "TlsNotSupported" error message when I try to use the mime-mail-ses package to send email. I read this documentation (below) that seems to specify port numbers for STARTTLS (as opposed to TLS) but neither mime-mail-ses or mime-mail seem to have a way to specify port numbers, if that in fact were a remedy to the problem.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html

```
ses = SES seFrom seTo seAccessKey seSecretKey seSessionToken seRegion

sMail' = simpleMail' mFrom mTo body L.empty

main = do  
  manager <- newManager defaultManagerSettings  
  renderSendMailSES manager ses sMail'
```

I get the following message:

```
Exception: HttpExceptionRequest Request {  
  ...
  port     = 443
  ...}  
TlsNotSupported
```

Comment: I hope you have that port opened for access in your AWS settings.

Comment: @Sibi, thanks for your response. That port isn't one of the ones listed in my AWS settings and I don't see a way of including it on there. Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `defaultManagerSettings` does not provide TLS support. Instead, you need to use a TLS enabled manager, such as with:

- Using [`tlsManagerSettings`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.4/http-client-tls-0.3.5.3/Network-HTTP-Client-TLS.html#v:tlsManagerSettings) with `newManager`
- Use [`newTlsManager`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.4/http-client-tls-0.3.5.3/Network-HTTP-Client-TLS.html#v:newTlsManager)
- Use the global manager, which defaults to TLS enabled, via [`getGlobalManager`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.4/http-client-tls-0.3.5.3/Network-HTTP-Client-TLS.html#v:getGlobalManager)

Comment: thanks!, and for authoring the packages mime-mail[-ses] too. I tried the three options and got the following message each time: [I am sure my credentials are correct]

Comment: *** Exception: SESException {seStatus = Status {statusCode = 403, statusMessage = "Forbidden"}, seCode = "SignatureDoesNotMatch", seMessage = "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."...}

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem there is, but it's definitely unrelated to the TLS issue. There could be lots of things at play, even something like a clock skew.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, the original TLS problem was definitely solved by your suggestion. I may raise the latest unrelated  issue as a separate question.

Comment: @madmonk Did you manage to solve the `SignatureDoesNotMatch` issue? Right now, I'm facing that exact problem.

Comment: @MarcoToniut Yes, I did. Trying to retrace my steps but my memory is a bit fuzzy now. As far as I remember, I had to set up AWS access keys and use those credentials in my code. Here is a link on setting up AWS credentials in case you haven't. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html)

Comment: Thanks @madmonk. I had done the appropriate setup already, yes, and tested the same access information against three different Haskell libraries and a Javascript one, with only the latter working. I'm really not sure what's going on, but I bet it's related to some specific edge case being triggered by common binaries in my local configuration. This was so annoying that I ended up setting a smtp server with SendGrid instead :-P